# Trouble aligning front disc brake - rotor noise

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I'm having trouble getting my front brakes aligned properly and staying aligned. The brakes are Tektro HDR-210 - I asked Tektro and they should be an OEM version of the HDR-310. I've just installed new Shimano B01S pads.

The brakes make a rubbing sound as in this video. This was shot just after I aligned the calliper by loosening the mounting bolts, holding the brakes on, and then tightening the bolts while the brakes are held on.

I noticed that the noise only happens when the lower mounting bolt on the fork is tightened. I've tried tightening the bolts in different orders but it hasn't made a difference: as soon as the bottom bolt is tight the rotor starts rubbing. Before tightening the lower bolt everything seems well aligned. The rotor seems pretty true visually to me.

I had to remove a little brake fluid to get the pistons to fully retract before the rotor would fit between the pads at all. I couldn't get any air to come out of the line. Braking at the front seems fine, about the same as the rear brakes that I haven't worked on.

Maybe once I've worn the pads a little there won't be any friction? It doesn't seem to be seriously affecting the wheel's rotation at the moment.

Is there something I can do to reduce the noise? Is this something that I should be concerned about or is it safe to ignore?

Update: I rode today, having not ridden yesterday. I guess in the ~48hrs since the last ride the brake fluid settled: the first pump of the front brakes was basically loose. After that they worked as well as the rear. I span the front wheel before I set out and it didn't seem to be making the rubbing noise, but it was there when I got back.

If nothing else I'm going to bleed & top up the line. I'm still not sure why the pad would be rubbing the rotor.

Comment: Are you sure that's the disc rubbing on the pads? If they're rubbing I wouldn't expect the wheel to freewheel for that amount of time

Comment: @DanK it's definitely the disc rubbing something, it's a bit hard to see with everything installed. I don't know what else it could be rubbing unless it's the pad holder or possibly the calliper. I think the pads & holder would be in the way of the disc rubbing anything else and it only makes noise when the bottom mounting bolt is tightened on the caliper.

Comment: @DanK it takes very little to make the rotor make a noise.  Freewheeling for that long with a rather musical ping once per revolution, or a near-constant singing wouldn't be remarkable on either of my disc-equipped bikes.  This noise isn't as clean though, and you can hear the slowing as well.

Comment: It's hard to be sure from the video, but it looks like the pads on both sides are clear at least some of the time.  I do wonder if the rotor could be touching the brake housing on the inside